# I have changed the default port of apache but now I can't access my website using Domain name?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have changed the default apache ports but now to access my website I have to put example.com:7648 I can't access it directly by typing the domain name I have to put port as well... So how to fix this issue.... I want to access my website by typing just domain name.

I'm using apache 2 and ubuntu os + webmin + virtualmin.

Comment: To fix this issue you need to use the default ports.

Comment: There must be some way

Comment: There is no other way. When you connect to a web server using browser, browser needs to know the port to connect to. By default, it tries port 80 for http and port 443 for https. What is your actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to free the port 80 and 443 to install other program........(Discourse Forums) discourse.org

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: You should install Discourse on a separate (virtual) machine with a distinct IP address. It will not get along with other web server software.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to access your website without typing the ports is to use the default ports. If you change the ports you need to provide them for every request.

Comment: There must be some way

Comment: @OnTheSky No, that's not how it works. You must use the default ports, or specify the non-default port in the URL. Wishing for some magic will not make reality change.