# Using main server to access to another server in the same IP range

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have two servers, lets call A (main) and B (other). B needs a VPN in order to acess and A doesn't need a vpn and is in the same IP range. I want to use A server in order to access B server without using a VPN, I tried using Redirects and ProxyPass, but didn't work as well since the user still require a VPN in order to access to B server.

How can you access to B server through A server without using a VPN? The main is using apache2 and the other is a GitLab server using NGINX.

It would be something like this:

Client --------> Server A --------> Server B

Right now is this:

Client -------> Server A

Client -------> vpn -------> Server B

**Using Mod_Proxy**

The first approach I used was mod_proxy configuration in apache2.conf file.

Adding the lines

```
ProxyPass "/gitlab" "xxx.xxx.x.xxx" 
ProxyPassReverse "/gitlab" "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
```

Meaning xxx.xxx.x.xxx is the IP of the Server B, the result was the same as an redirect, the client uses Server A without VPN to go throuh /gitlab and goes to Server B, but still need a VPN in order to access Server B.

Comment: Use HAProxy or even mod_proxy.  If you've tried them, then show the config/error that you've tried.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, I don't get any errors by doing mod_proxy and I edited in order to show the configuration and explain what happened, I will test HAProxy and edit the question soon.

Comment: You need to configure the backend server correctly to work behind a reverse proxy. See https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server/1035017#1035017