# Have different hostings on the same domain

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4

My organization has the following setup:

- https://www.example.com --> Drupal website on AWS, using Apache 2.4.29
- https://www.example.com/static-stuff/whatever --> A node holding the content of a static HTML page in the body.

Now, we aim to decouple the Drupal pages from the static ones. But due to a strange policy from our hosting provider, this will mean that the HTML pages will have to be moved to an external hosting.

To be:

- https://www.example.com --> stay as is
- https://www.example.com/static-stuff/whatever ---> static HTML page, hosted externally (e.g. on Github Pages)

From what I understood, it's easy to achieve this by creating a new subdomain (e.g. https://static-stuff.example.com/whatever) and then a redirection.
But is there a way to achieve this without altering the URLs? What type of changes would be required on the Apache and DNS settings?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

A browser will go to whatever IP address `www.example.com` resolves to in the DNS.

The server running at that address will need to act as a proxy to fetch the static content, or redirect the browser to the external location.  There are various ways to do this using HAProxy, `mod_proxy`, Apache RewriteRules, etc.

However, there is no way to get `www.example.com` to resolve to different IP addresses based on the path (URL).