# NGINX proxy_pass without changing URL

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass, url

### My Goal

My goal is to redirect to a different web page without changing the URL in the address bar. So for example I want to redirect from `https://my.site.com/path` to `https://external.com/other`, but only the content of the page should change, not the URL.

### Current configuration

This is what I have tried. I thought, that `proxy_redirect` might be a good idea, so I based the configuration on the [NGINX docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect). But while this does load the content of `https://external.com/other`, the URL in the address bar changes to `https://my.site.com/other`. The domain name stays the same, but the path changes.

```
location = /path {
    proxy_pass https://external.com/other;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No, that doesn't answer my question. I'm basically doing what the answer suggests, but I don't want the path in the URL to change, when making a request. I want it to stay the same, while only the content of the site changes.

Comment: No, you are not doing it. What you want is not a redirect, it's a plain reverse proxy.

Comment: Chances are that the redirect you are still getting from the backend server, which needs to be configured properly.