# Without port site is not working http://askothers.net:8080

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, bitnami

How can I fix it without a port?

http://askothers.net:8080 is working but http://askothers.net is not working

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName askothers.net
    ServerAlias www.askothers.net
    Redirect / https://www.askothers.net/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName askothers.net
    ServerAlias www.askothers.net
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/askothers.net"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/askothers.net/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/askothers.net/privkey.pem"
    ServerAdmin info@askothers.net
    ErrorLog "logs/askothers.net-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/askothers.net-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Answer (score 2):

The default port for HTTP is port 80. Your server is on 8080.

You have to change your port to follow the standards, which is port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: port 80 has been used for nginx server. I'm using apach server

Comment: Then either use your Nginx server or use Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache. There is no other way.