# Reverse proxy to direct different users to corresponding locations

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, authorization

I have a server. One of its functions is [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net). This app has no per-user authorization, only admin. So I decided to run different Syncthing instances for each user.

For authorization process I would like to use unix user names and passwords (from /etc/passwd).

I imaging to use nginx as the reverse proxy and authorization verifier. Could you please verify my idea and help me with examples.

Sample services layout:

- Syncthing user1 listens on 127.0.0.1:8384
- Syncthing user2 listens on 127.0.0.1:8385
- Syncthing user3 listens on 127.0.0.1:8386
- Nginx (or other) listens on all interfaces including IPv6 on default HTTPS port 0.0.0.0:433

Address would be https://synxrage.local/syncthing. Port must never appear in URLs.

Depending on successfully authorized user proxy directs to different internal port and user sees his admin panel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: @vidarlo not really. The actual problem (use different backends for different authenticated users) is not addressed there. I don't know if that is even possible.

Comment: [this ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/439) suggests the [`$remote_user` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user). It should be possible to use this to define the backend server to use.

Comment: thank you guys for comments

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this nagged me and it was actually quite easy using the [`$remote_user` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user).

To enable PAM auth you need to do some things:

Install `nginx-extras`:

```
sudo apt -y install nginx-extras
```

Create `/etc/pam.d/nginx`  and add the following content:

```
auth       include      common-auth
account    include      common-account
```

Allow nginx to read the shadow file:

```
sudo usermod -aG shadow www-data
```

<sub>Instructions [found here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=nginx&f=10).</sub>

Now you can configure nginx

```conf
# configure one upstream per user
# give it the name of the user that logs in

upstream usera {
    server localhost:8384;
}

upstream userb {
    server localhost:8385;
}

upstream userc {
    server localhost:8386;
}

# now configure the actual reverse proxy

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        # add pam authentication
        auth_pam "PAM Authentication";
        auth_pam_service_name "nginx";

        # configure reverse proxy to connect to the per-user backend
        proxy_pass http://$remote_user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to manage upstream dynamically. I mean add or remove users depending on changing users list at runtime. I even think for a UID based math: UID-1000+8384? where UID is Linux User ID. First user has usually id 1000.

Comment: Big thank you!!