# connecting domain to a server and port forwarding to show website hosted on another server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, domain, apache2, port-forwarding

I have a website on server A with IP address of 1.1.1.1 and the domain is example.com.
I also have another server B which IP address is 2.2.2.2.
I want to connect the domain example.net to server B and somehow config the server so when users browse example.net it connects to server A shows content of example.com.
Also it should send users actual IP address in header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: You could do a split DNS configuration. That way your recursive DNS server would provide different results then the actual authoritative server.