# Open up localhost port to outside world

Tags: iptables, centos7, port-forwarding, localhost, external-connection

I have a http service running on localhost port 8080 on a centos 7 machine. Is there any way I can route / port forward incoming and outgoing traffic through my external interface. So, mapping `127.0.0.1:8080` to `<my external ip address>:8080`?

I'd also like to do the same with https if possible as well.

I don't have access to the application code, so would prefer an iptables / port forwarding solution if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: Or you could just bind it to the external interface as well ...

Comment: I don't really have the application code available, so was wondering if i could do something with iptables

Comment: @GeraldSchneider We shouldn't encourage people to expose localhost, mapping to external is the right way to go so it can be separated from internal work

Answer (score 0):

The REDIRECT target is probably the answer:

https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#REDIRECTTARGET