# Apache reverse proxy websockets correct way

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

```
<Client A> <---> <Server A: reverse proxy> <----> <Server B>
```

I don't want the `Client A` to connect to `Server B` directly, well it shouldn't that's why I'm using a reverse proxy, `Server B` can be easily accessed by `Server A` on the other hand `Server B` has a lot of limitations on bandwidth and ... if accessed directly from `Client A`.

I'm feeling like my config on `Server A` is simply forwarding the connections to `Server B` instead of doing anything itself, and Clients directly connect to `Server B` at the end which isn't ideal.

I feel this because I'm supposed to get the same result with different ISPs since `Server A` works great in all those ISPs, but no I get some slow connections, some fast ones and that means probably they are connecting to `Server B` directly.

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /rooms/325 wss://cdn.dummy.com:443/rooms/325
ProxyPassReverse /rooms/325 wss://cdn.dummy.com:443/rooms/325
```

Here's my config, it works but I don't think it is right at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: @djdomi Thanks so much but not really, I still don't understand if the reverse proxy only forwards the connection making the client directly connect to the endpoint or the reverse proxy becomes itself a client for the endpoint and a server for the client