# Apache ProxyPass only proxying URL, but not page assets

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

So I currently have a proxy configuration that looks like the following:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/foo/bar/(.+)$ https://xyz.domain.net/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/foo/bar/(.+)$ https://xyz.domain.net/$1

ProxyPreserveHost Off
```

I'm trying to map, for example, `https://my.website.com/foo/bar/home` to `https://xyz.domain.net/home`.

The proxypass seems to be working as I can see the webpage from `xyz.domain.net/home`, however the webpage is the ONLY thing that seems to be being proxied. All other assets such as js files or fonts are not being correctly requested.

For example, when loading `https://xyz.domain.net/home` this page fetches `https://xyz.domain.net/scripts/index.js`. However, when accessing it via the proxy URL `https://my.website.com/foo/bar/home` the asset is instead attempted to be retrieved from `https://my.website.com/scripts/index.js` and of course is responded with a 404.

Is there any other proxy directive which I must include in order for the assets loaded by the page to also be retrieved from the `xyz.domain` server?

As another piece of information, I've attempted `ProxyPreserveHost On` instead of `Off` but this retrieves a 403 from the end server on every page I try to access to.

I am using Oracle HTTP Server version 12.2.1.4

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: See the section `Backend configuration`

Comment: Hi Gerald. Which part of that section do you mean exactly? I should mention that I don't have access to the xyz server configurations

Comment: I will edit my post, but I should have been clearer, I am using OHS rather than Apache. Both `ProxyHTMLURLMap` `ProxyHTMLExtended` keywords aren't accepted. The rest of the configuration seems to be exactly as described there

Comment: You need the `mod_proxy_html` module for that. If that is not available configuring the backend with the correct URLs is the only way.

Comment: Hi Gerald. We have been able to install mod_proxy_html on the apache and load the module on httpd.conf. Is it possible to just modify the relativate path of the html using this module, just for everything after the `^/foo/bar/(.*)$` endpoints?

Comment: From reading the documentation of the module I would assume yes.

Comment: I have attempted `ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com/(.*)$ ^/foo/bar/$1 R` but unfortunately when the proxied page is loaded it's still trying to retrieve the assets from the `^/foo/bar` server