# (Nginx proxy) Replace host in response in headers and body

Tags: nginx, proxypass

It's possible in nginx to replace "Host" header in request.

```
    server_name myexample.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host myendpoint.net;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8111;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

However, is it possible to replace all matches "myendpoint.net" to "myexample.com" both in headers and response body?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: See the last paragraph of the linked answer.

Comment: It is however preferable to configure the correct URL on your backend server.